# Why gets "a" element split in Browser DOM

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I don't understand what's happening here.

My Source code looks like this (one a Element arround an H2 and a DIV):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="de"> 
    <head>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div class="mainarea"> 
            <p>Test 123</p>
            <a class='artprev' href='artikeldetail-62b0a5794c6c870009e34f71.html'>
                <h2>DLRG / SCHWIMMKURS</h2>
                <div class='content'>
                    <img src='boy-swimming.png'>
                    <p style='textAlign:start;' class=''>Das DLRG bietet auch im Jahr 2022 wieder Schwimmkurse an.</p>
                    <p style='textAlign:start;' class=''>Bei Fragen und für die Anmeldung zum Schwimmkurs wenden Sie sich direkt an die Ortsgruppe, über&nbsp;
                        <a href="https://dlrg.de/">die Homepage der DLRG Ortsgruppe</a>.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

When rendered in Chrome (didn't check other browsers, yet) the DOM Insprectors shows it like this (multiple elements surrounding other elements):

```
<html lang="de"><head>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div class="mainarea"> 
            <p>Test 123</p>
            <a class="artprev" href="artikeldetail-62b0a5794c6c870009e34f71.html">
                <h2>DLRG / SCHWIMMKURS</h2>
                </a><div class="content"><a class="artprev" href="artikeldetail-62b0a5794c6c870009e34f71.html">
                    <img src="boy-swimming.png">
                    <p style="textAlign:start;" class="">Das DLRG bietet auch im Jahr 2022 wieder Schwimmkurse an.</p>
                    </a><p style="textAlign:start;" class=""><a class="artprev" href="artikeldetail-62b0a5794c6c870009e34f71.html">Bei Fragen und für die Anmeldung zum Schwimmkurs wenden Sie sich direkt an die Ortsgruppe, über&nbsp;
                        </a><a href="https://dlrg.de/">die Homepage der DLRG Ortsgruppe</a>.
                    </p>
                </div>
            
        </div>
     
</body></html>
```

Can anyone explain me what's happening here and why? (I actually want the a beeing a clickable box arround all the CMS generated elements inside).

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, the html code above is directly taken from the browser as well with "view-source:", so whatever happens happens inside the browser. 
And to anticipate the next question: "no", there's not a single line of JavaScript code or any external library included.

Comment: You have TWO closing `</a>` tags in your original code, the first of them just before the last closing `</p>` tag, which the browser tries to interpret in some way to make it still work. Remove that and it will work.

Comment: @wOxxOm It behaves the same in Firefox and in Chrome Incognito mode, I updated the examle, so it contains the whole source code.

Comment: @Johannes Douhhh.... That's it. one can't nest <a> 's. That puts me into another problem, but that should be solvable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by @Johannes in the comments: The mess is caused by my traying to nest an `<a></a>`-Tag in another `<a></a>`-Tag. That's not part of the HTML spec, but the browser still tries to come up with something useable,